# Occlusion Culling for Grid Aligned Cells

Tags: 3d, occlusion

Given:

1. A 3d, axis aligned grid of cells with side length L.
2. A plane with start position, side L and a axis aligned normal;
3. A arbitrary positioned/rotated camera with variable vertical field of view

**I need to check what cells lies completely behind the plane**

Desired Result:

- [Side View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWds8.png)
- [Camera View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8xvj.png)

I don't know if it is relevant, but in my case, the plane start/end components will always be aligned with the grid, with exception of the component its normal is pointing to; The exemple images show a plane with normal (0, 0, -1) so the x and y components are aligned, but not z;